# Which groups act freely on $S^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, group-cohomology

When $n$ is even, it is easy to classify groups which [act freely](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FreeAction.html) on $S^n$ using degree theory: if $G$ acts on $S^n$, then associating to each element $g \in G$ the degree of the map obtained from multiplication by $g$, one gets a map $d : G \to \{\pm 1\}$. It is easy to verify this is a homomorphism. If $G$ acts freely, multiplication by any element $g$ is a fixed point free map, thus $d(g) = (-1)^{n+1} = -1$, making $d$ injective. The only nontrivial group which injects into $\Bbb Z/2$ is itself, so we're done.

However, a lot of groups act freely on $S^n$ for odd $n$. For example, $\Bbb Z/p$ acts on $S^3$ freely for all prime $p$ (so called lens space action). What do we know about such groups? Is it possible to classify them?

If $G$ is a finite group acting freely on $S^3$, then as free action of finite groups on Hausdorff spaces is properly discontinuous, quotient map $S^3 \to S^3/G$ is a covering projection. Thus $S^3/G$ is a closed 3-manifold with fundamental group $G$, hence $G$ is a closed 3-manifold group. On the other hand, if $G$ is a closed 3-manifold group, let $M$ be that manifold and $G$ must act on $\tilde{M}$ freely. But $\tilde{M}$ is a simply connected closed 3-manifold hence homeomorphic to $S^3$ by Poincare conjecture, so $G$ must act on $S^3$ freely.

Thus, finite groups acting freely on $S^3$ are precisely the finite closed 3-manifold groups. But what about infinite groups? Given an infinite group, how can we tell if it acts on $S^3$ or not? More generally, what about groups acting freely on $S^n$ for some fixed odd $n > 1$?

---

[edit] I am only interested in actions of discrete groups. Also, any sort of general remark (long enough to not fit as a comment) or partial answers (like the answers below) are welcome to me, you can post them as answers.

Comment: see page 4 [here](https://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/geomtop.pdf) for a cohomological criterion on G

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Why the image of $d$ is $\{\pm 1\}$? it represent for orientation-preserving and reversing isometries? i.e. all isometry are whether homotop with identity map or its negative?

Comment: BalarkaSen: my question was too obvious that you didn't answer it or you didn't see the comment?

Comment: I saw it, planned to respond and afterwards forgot about it. The group action is by homeomorphisms, and every self-homeomorphism of S^n has degree +1 or -1.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: In your knowledge, the answer to the title is incomplete up to 2022?

Answer (score 16):

Here are some thoughts. If a finite group $G$ acts on $S^n$ freely, then it's automatically a covering space action as $S^n$ is Hausdorff. Thus, $\pi_1(S^n/G) \cong G$. Moreover, $\pi_i(S^n/G) \cong \pi_i(S^n) \cong 0$ for all $i < n$. $\pi_n(S^n/G) \cong \pi_n(S^n)$ which is infinite cyclic. Pick a map $S^n \to S^n/G$ representing the generator, and glue a $D^{n+1}$ along it to kill $\pi_n$. Kill $\pi_k$ for all $k > n$ similarly by gluing cells along maps representing generators of $\pi_k$ for each dimension $k$, to infinity if necessary.

One then obtains a $K(G, 1)$ from attaching just one $(n+1)$-cell to $S^n/G$. Thus, the group cohomology $H^{n+1}(G; \Bbb Z/p)$ is either $\Bbb Z/p$ or $0$ for any prime $p$ cellular cohomology.

As a corollary, for example, $\Bbb Z/2 \times \Bbb Z/2$ cannot act on any $S^n$ freely for any $n$, as by Kunneth formula

$$H^{n+1}(\Bbb Z/2 \times \Bbb Z/2; \Bbb Z/2) \cong \bigoplus_{i + j = n+1} H^i(\Bbb Z/2; \Bbb Z/2) \otimes H^j(\Bbb Z/2; \Bbb Z/2)$$

which is simply isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/2)^{n+1}$, violating the previous obstruction. Similarly, $\Bbb Z/p \times \Bbb Z/p$ does not act on $S^n$ for any prime $p$. However, similar technique doesn't work for infinite groups. Also, can any obstruction be placed over higher group cohomologies?

Answer (score 13):

You have already given answers yourself. I only have a two comments, with a recent reference, which you might have already seen.

If a finite group $G$ acts freely on a sphere then we know that all abelian subgroups of $G$ are cyclic, i.e., that $G$ has periodic cohomology, and that all elements of order $2$ are central. In particular, $G$ has at most one element of order $2$. For even-dimensional spheres there is only $C_2$, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136126/the-only-finite-group-which-can-act-freely-on-even-dimensional-spheres-is-c-2).

For infinite groups, free actions of *discrete* groups have been studied a lot.
A free action of a discrete group $G$ on an $n$-homotopy sphere $\Sigma(n)$ induces an action on $H^n(\Sigma(n),\mathbb{Z})$, i.e., an homomorphism $G\rightarrow Aut(H^n(\Sigma(n),\mathbb{Z}))$. For $G$ finite, and $n$ odd, this action is trivial.
If the group $G$ is infinite there are more possibilities for the induced action of $G$, which makes it more difficult to characterise these induced actions.  For a summary of some results and a certain classification see the recent preprint on [Free and properly discontinuous actions of groups on homotopy $2n$-spheres](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0124.pdf).

Comment: Can you give a reference or proof of the fact that all abelian subgroups of $G$ are cyclic? +1.

Comment: A reference is Theorem $2$ [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~keenan/actions.pdf).

Comment: The second paragraph is very close to being the classification of which groups act on (some) sphere: all it's missing is the condition that every subgroup of order $2p$ is cyclic. (That is, that the dihedral group $D_{2p}$ is not a subgroup.)

Answer (score 8):

This has almost but not quite been stated a few times, so to clear the air: the answer is known for finite groups, it is due to [Madsen, Thomas, and Wall](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/wall7.pdf), and it says that a finite group $G$ acts freely on some sphere if and only if

1. all of the abelian subgroups of $G$ are cyclic; equivalently, the cohomology is periodic; equivalently, $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ does not occur as a subgroup for any prime $p$; and
2. every element of order $2$ is central.

The necessity of the first condition is due to Smith and the necessity of the second condition is due to Milnor. This is taken from the introduction to Alejandro Adem's *[Constructing and Deconstructing Group Actions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212280)*.

Comment: I think Quaternions satisfies in these two criteria. So they act freely ..?

Comment: @C.F.G Consider the $3$-manifold obtained from the cube $I^3$ by pasting opposing pairs of sides by a 90 degree twist; this in fact has fundamental group $Q_8$ (this is an exercise in Hatcher somewhere). So $Q_8$ is a finite $3$-manifold group, thus acts on $S^3$ freely. This manifold is a lot like the Poincare homology sphere, if you wish, except that's constructed with the dodecahedron instead of the cube.

Comment: Alternatively one can construct it as follows; $V_4$ is a subgroup of $SO(3)$, and $Q_8$ is a central $\Bbb Z_2$-extension of $V_4$ so is a subgroup of $SU(2)$ (in fact it's $i, j, k$ acting on the unit quaternions). The action of $Q_8$ on $S^3 = SU(2)$ is by left multiplication. The manifold above is $SO(3)/V_4$, analogous to Poincare homology sphere, once again.

Comment: @Qiaochuyuan: Hatcher (p.75) says that "$G$ contains at most one element of order 2". So together your second restriction it becomes: "$G$ contains at most one element of order 2 and if exist any it is unique and central."

Answer (score 3):

There are noncyclic finite groups that act freely as rotations of $\Bbb S^n$ for odd
$n > 1$. These actions are classified quite explicitly in [*Joseph A. Wolf*; Spaces of Constant Curvature
 1984](https://bookstore.ams.org/chel-372-h).

There is a theorem assert that

> The group $\Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb Z_p$, where $p$ is prime, **cannot** act freely on
>   any sphere.

Comment: I have given a proof of this theorem below in my answer; an alternative argument is that if $G$ is a finite group acting freely on $S^n$ then $G$ has periodic cohomology (although the converse is false, take $G = S_3$, see eg Dietrich Burde's answer). Good point that space forms of constant positive curvature are sphere quotients though, I will try to read the reference to see how a classification goes. One should note that there are wild topological actions of finite groups on spheres, eg, there is a free Z_2 action on S^7 not conjugate to the antipodal action, giving fake RP^7 quotients

Comment: Sorry. I missed last paragraph of your answer. Anyway, the first part of your question is so interesting for me. (using degree theory). this is your argument or it is from a book? any reference?

Comment: @BalarkaSen: $Z_2$ act on standard 7 sphere or exotic 7 sphere?

Comment: That $\Bbb Z_2$ is the only group that can act on $S^n$ for even $n$ is standard. See for example Hatcher. The wild $\Bbb Z_2$-action on $S^7$ that I mentioned is constructed in Milnor-Hirsch, "Some curious involutions of spheres"; they do use Milnor's exotic $S^7$ to construct it, and the $\Bbb Z_2$-action is antipodal action on the $S^3$ fibers of the bundle $S^3 \to S^7 \to S^4$ in the construction of Milnor's 7-sphere